# Simulate Initial Login of user without using sudo

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

I'm writing a script to interface 2 third-party programs.  (Datadog and AWS)

The data mining script uses `sudo -u` to run my script.

The script that I need to retrieve data from will segfault if initial login is not simulated.

The data mining script does not have permission to `sudo`.

I can reproduce the error like this:

```
[me] ~$ sudo -u dd-agent aws
[me] ~$ echo $?
139
```

Of course, if I do a `sudo -iu` and run the command, it works just fine.

Is it possible to simulate initial login without going through `sudo`?

Comment: I _do_ have a reason for not wanting to modify the sudoers file:  Doing so would require having the automation that spins up our servers manage the sudoers file, which is dangerous.

Comment: Have you considered using TCL/TK "expect" or something similar?

Comment: do you know what's specifically causing the segfault? Is it because environment variables from `.profile` are not being set? You could explicitly `source .profile` in the `sudo` shell.

Answer (score 2):

For login simulation (without going through "sudo -i"), you have to use "su" command.

Checking the man page for parameter '-':

```
-, -l, --login
          Starts the shell as login shell with an environment similar to a real login:

             o      clears all environment variables except for TERM

             o      initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, PATH

             o      changes to the target user's home directory

             o      sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a login shell
```

Also, you have to use *[here-doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)*.

As an example, you can check this printing logged user's id using the 'id' command:

```
#\bin\bash

id

su - user <<EOF
userPassword
id
#here you can execute your script

EOF

id
```

Also, if your program does a segmentation fault.. it tries to access to another memory segment that not belongs to the program.